# What files can I access?

Tags: windows, networking

I am on a network here at school and they have recently redone some of the computers and our computer science room. Our network administrator isn't very helpful at all, and thanks to him no computer science people can access their drive. For instance, I had my work saved on \newserver\NT1_Users... and he has moved my folder to \newserver\students... yet some of the other computer science students can still access NT1_Users.. anyways, I was wondering if there is some how a way to just list what folders I have access to (on the network), or at least view my rights/privileges on the network so that I just don't go stumbling around blindly?

For example, when you go to My Computer -> Manage, you can view the user accounts on that computer and their rights, etc.. But I have a network account, and is there a place similar to that I can go without being the administrator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool AccessEnum http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332 that will list access information for files and directories.  If you don't have access to something you will seen access denied.  If you do have access, then you will see who else has access.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't have a way to provide a list for your access on networked machines.  Aside from putting \\newserver in Explorer to see what shares are visible and manually trying each share, you would probably need some kind of penetration testing tool that will test for open shares (probably not a good idea at a school).

Comment: +1 for the probably not a good idea at a school.